# TSLint setup: Prevent void as function return

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

Is it a way to configure TSLint to prevent `void` as explicit return function value?

Usually, problem comes from Angular hooks which by default declared as

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

and this code is substituted by IDE

what I want is to have this

```
  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

and if I have `void` somewhere as return value it should be highlighted.

My motivation, TS automatically infers void type if function doesn't have return expression, so this extra declaration is not needed and pollutes the code.

Comment: Hi!  You might want to read the documentation on how to develop your own tslint rules.  This is probably helpful:  https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/
  
Looks like you'll need to specify this command line flag when running tslint: `--rules-dir`

Comment: @GordonBurgett so, you think it's not possible to achieve with standard rules?

Comment: Here's a list of all the standard ts-lint rules.  If you can't find one here that does what you want, then yes it's not possible to achieve with standard rules.
https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/

A quick scan shows these two which may be of interest to you: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/invalid-void/  https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-void-expression/

Comment: Thanks, I checked that as well. But I'm very familiar with TSLint rules, so maybe I missed something.